# Can I disconnect a Corian Sink Overflow tube?

Tags: smell, overflow

We have noticed a foul odor from our sink which has the corian overflow tube (made out of plastic) that sits outside the bowl.  As soon as we turn the water on, the odor appears.  I have taken it apart, cleaned it and poured chemicals down the tube and drain.  The odor occurs again and again.  There is water in the p-trap so I know it is not sewer gas.  It is simply a poor design.

I have a pfister faucet with a pop-up drain stopper.  The Overflow tube fits right below the drain on the under mounted sink.  We know that we will never have water reach the overflow.

Question...Can I seal the overflow tube and the connection at the pipe so that these smells don’t occur and no water becomes stagnant?

Just looking for ideas before my wife wants a new sink.

Comment: What chemicals have you poured down the drain?.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that there is hair or other gunk in the sink tailpiece or caught in the stopper.  It absorbs some of the sewage and then gets really nasty.  The stink could then freely travel out.  Try taking out the stopper and cleaning any gunk you might find.

This would solve the stink problem.

To answer the question about the overflow being sealed... it would violate plumbing code almost surely.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the following does the trick on a similar bathroom lavatory: Run a couple of quarts of hot water from the tap. Pour 1/2 cup of undiluted Chlorox into the drain and rinse with a couple of 1/2 cup portions of hot water. Let sit for an hour or more, then run water from the tap.

Use a small plunger on the drain if necessary. Hold your fingers or hand over the overflow while plunging.

**EDIT** Plunge as follows: Get a [special plunger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07259W7MZ) for a lavatory. Fill the sink with water w/ detergent. Open the drain; let water into the drain and trap; plunge with the sink half full. Push gently and pull strongly. You will know when you have the tail piece and trap clean when plunging the sink no longer pulls particles into the bowl.